# How can I restrict RAM usage for a particular user or process?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, memory, quota

I'm using a background service that leaks memory from time to time. To prevent using the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd> <kbd>REISUB</kbd>[[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REISUB)], I'd like to restrict the RAM usage for one process or a system user.

I really would like to say: User x may use the maximum amount of RAM of 1 GB.

Is this feasible? Do I need kind of virtual machine for this? I'm using Ubuntu 9.10.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[ulimit](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Tips%20and%20Tricks/ulimit.htm) is your friend. Check out the -m flag. I *think* you set this before you launch your process and it applies from then on (in the current shell).

Comment: Thanks, nice hint! As I understand ulimit, it limits _all_ users memory/process/whatever consumption. I just like to limit it to one user/process & subprocesses.

Comment: ulimit is a shell command, and only affects processes started from the same shell after ulimit is executed.  You startup the process in a shell script with a ulimit command to have it affect just that process.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the shell commands `ulimit` (for bash) or `limit` (for csh), you can control this from inside your code with the `ulimit()` function.

Comment: Obligatory manpages: http://linux.die.net/man/1/ulimit (shell command) and http://linux.die.net/man/3/ulimit (C function).